# Need reference for chromatic number

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, coloring

I need a reference (one that has a *doi* if possible) for the statement, "there is no *general* formula for finding the chromatic number of any graph"

Comment: Hard to get a reference for the non-existence of a formula.  Computing the chromatic number of a graph is an NP-complete problem, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karp%27s_21_NP-complete_problems).  Maybe that's enough?

Comment: The contraction-deletion algorithm is super-exponential in the worst case, but can produce the chromatic polynomial for any graph, and then the chromatic number follows trivially. Does that count as a formula?

Comment: Thanks @lulu, I used a Karp's 21 NP-Complete problems as a reference.

Comment: As for @zhuli, I don't really get your reply- i'm not looking for a formula nor an algorithm in this question- still, thanks.

Comment: zhuli meant that you could argue there *is* a "general formula" for the chromatic number, namely the [contraction-deletion formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deletion%E2%80%93contraction_formula) for the chromatic number. Though computing the chromatic number from it requires e.g. applying it recursively until you get to edgeless graphs (with $k^n$ k-colorings). So you should probably specify that you mean an efficiently computable formula (more formally, a poly-time algorithm).

Comment: (more precisely, the formula gives the number of $k$-colorings for any $k$, denoted $\chi_G(k)$, but you can use $\max_k [\chi_G(k) > 0]$ to get a formula for the chromatic number).

Comment: Another example of a *general formula* for the number of k-colorings (but not efficiently computable) is $\sum_f \prod_{uv \in E} [f(u) \neq f(v)]$, where the sum is over all functions $V \to [k]$ and where $[f(u) \neq f(v)]$ is the Iverson bracket, which can also be written as $1 - 0^{|f(u) - f(v)|}$